# Jenkins API - Unable to get jobs from specific fodler

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-api

I am trying to copy a folder(with jobs) by reading the config file of those jobs and creating jobs using those config files.
I am unable to fetch the jobs in the folder. (but i am able to get all the jobs i.e jobs outside the folder and inside the folder)

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: import jenkins
class JenkinsApi:
    def __init__(self, username, password, src_job, new_job):
        self.url = "http://localhost:8080/"
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.source_job_name = src_job
        self.new_job_name = new_job
    def create_jenkins_instance(self):
        js = jenkins.Jenkins(url=self.url, username=self.username, password=self.password)
        return  js
  
    jen = JenkinsApi('admin', 'admin', 'testing', 'test')
    jenkin_instance = jen.create_jenkins_instance()
    print(jenkin_instance.get_all_jobs())